# How to install a dependency outside bower_components?

Tags: javascript, json, bower

I have a bower.json which looks like this and i want to install the jquery dependency outside the bower_components folder how would i do it?

```
{
 "name": "A project",
 "description": "bower components",
 "main": "testing.html",
 "license": "ISC",
"homepage": "",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"faker": "^4.1.0",
"pretender": "^1.4.2",
"jquery": "^3.2.1
}
}
```

Comment: why would you want to do that ?

Comment: I just wanted to know if it is possible to do it.Is it possible?

Comment: if you dont want to use jquery then why did you use it at the first place, You could have used the CDN